# C++ calculator and for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
string Expression::addevaluate(string x){
    stringrep = x;   //Stringrep is the string that user typed in, 
                     //it might be 5+6+7-8-9*3/(2+5)

    int totalnum = stringrep.length();

    for(int i=0;i < totalnum;i++){    //This for loop will seperate the 
                                      //string by "+" and output a vector 
                                      //with seperate string
        int addop = stringrep.find("+");
        addvector.push_back(stringrep.substr(0,addop));
        string a =stringrep.substr(0,addop);
        totalnum=totalnum-(a.length());
        stringrep = stringrep.substr(addop+1,totalnum);
    }
    int vectorlength = addvector.size();
    for(int i = 0;i<vectorlength;i++){
        cout << i+1<<":"<<addvector[i]<<",";
    }
    subevaluate(addvector); 

    return stringrep;

}

string Expression::subevaluate(vector<string> &v){
    int totalnum = v.size();
    //This is the question, I have no idea how can i set the value totalnum
    //If it's the size of vector,it's too small. If it's the last totalnum
    //from last function. Then there is a error. In addition,I do not know
    //what the error is.
    for(int i=0;i < totalnum;i++){
        int addop = v[i].find("-");
        if(addop > 0){
            subtvector.push_back(v[i].substr(0,addop));
            string a =v[i].substr(0,addop);
            totalnum=totalnum-a.length();
            v[i] = v[i].substr(addop+1,totalnum);
        }
    }
    int vectorlength = subtvector.size();
    for(int i = 0;i<vectorlength;i++){
        cout << i+1<<":"<<subtvector[i]<<",";
    }
    return stringrep;
}
```

I do not know why I did wrong for the second for loop. Please help me solve the for loop. In addition,how can i seperate all the string by."+","-","*","/". Then calculate the answer like a calculator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation will not work... suppose you have

```
"1+2*(3+4)"
```

the first split (even when written correctly) will get

- `"1"`
- `"2*(3"`
- `"4)"`

What are you going to do with `"2*(3"` ?

At the very minimum to write a calculator with this approach you need:

- add `"("` front and add `")"` at the end (i.e. change to `"(1+2*(3+4))"`
- look for **last** OPEN parenthesis
- move **from there** to the first CLOSED parenthesis
- process what is in-between (i.e. `"3+4"`) and replace the whole parenthesized expression it in the original string with the result (i.e. get from `"1+2*(3+4)"` to `"(1+2*7)"`)
- repeat until there are no more parenthesis

For splitting a string on a given character you should write a dedicated function, for example:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& text, char sep) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    size_t pos = text.find(sep);
    while(pos != std::string::npos) {
        result.push_back(text.substr(0, pos));
        text = text.substr(pos + 1);
    }
    result.push_back(text);
    return result;
}
```

then you can write

```
std::vector<std::string> res = split(text, '+');
```

to get from `"1+2*3+4"` to a vector containing `"1"`, `"2*3"`, `"4"`.

PS: Note that this way of computing expression is not what normally is done, but it can be made working so you should in my opinion keep working on it until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be difficult to make the code work when you split the string into a vector. The operator precedence will be too hard to handle, I think.

How about a recursive process?

In this way you can simplify the original string step by step. You just keep calling the evaluate function with substrings until they are turned into simple expressions.

Example:

exp = 12/(5+1)

call 1: call f("12/(5+1)")

call 1: f identifies the substring "5+1" and call itself (recursive)

call 2:    call f("5+1")

call 2:    simple expression calculates into "6" which is returned

call 1: The substring "(5+1)" is replaced by the returned "6"

call 1: exp now looks "12/6"

call 1: simple expression calculates into "2" which is returned

More complex expressions like "48/(5 + (2*3/(3-1))) would just result in more calls so that the string is simplified step by step.

The code could look like the code below. Only the structure is include - it is for OP to fill in the actual code.

```
bool isSimpleExpression(string& s)
{
    // Return true if s is simple, i.e. X+Y, X-Y, X*Y, X/Y
    // Otherwise false
}

string evaluateString(string& exp)
{
    while(!isSimpleExpression(exp))
    {
        // exp must be broken into smaller part as it isn't simple yet

        if (ExpContainsParanthesis() )
        {
            // Example: exp is "12/(5+1)"

            string s1 = FindSubstringInMostInnerMatchingParanthesis(exp);
            // Example: s1 is "5+1"

            // Example: call evaluateString("5+1")
            strint s2 = evaluateString(s1); // Recursive call
            // Example: s2 is 6

            ReplaceS1WithS2(exp, s1, s2);
            // Example: exp is "12/6"
        }
        else if (ExpContainsMultiplication())
        {
            // Find the substring with multiplication
            // Call this function with the substring
            // Replace the substring with the returned result 
        }
        else if ....
        {
           // division
        }
        // ... and so on
    }

    // Calculate the simple expression
    string result;

    // ..
    // ..

    return result;
}
```